# how to use overflow to scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, scroll, overflow

i have this situation:

```
<ul class="a1">
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
<li class="q1"></li>
</ul>

.q1{
width: 100px;
height: 250px;
background: red;
margin: 5px;
float: left;
}

.a1{
width: 500px;
height: 250px;
background: grey;
overflow: auto;
}
```

how can i make this to scroll horizontally and not vertically.

here is a test on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/t22W2/)

any ideas?

thanks.

edit. i need to see a scroll bar on a set width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the width of your `ul` to be as wide as all your `li`'s and only as tall as your tallest `li` including margins.

```
.a1{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 260px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/t22W2/1/

**1200px wide** = (100px * 10) + (5px * 10) + (5px * 10)

**260px tall** = 250px + 5px + 5px

Comment: i see no scroll bar, there has to be one on a set width

Comment: i see, but i need the  width: 700px; with a horizontal scroll

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

**EDIT**: Replaced `text-wrap:none;` with `white-space:nowrap;`

```
.a1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    -ms-overflow-y: hidden; /* IE8 hack */ 
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjcXe/) that demonstrates the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Can you try it again? I included a jsFiddle too.

Comment: +1, best answer. Simple, clean and totally easy to manage, this one should have been picked.